# Consistent number generator from multiple input variables

Tags: c#, math

I wan't to generate a *fictional* job title from some information I have about the visitor.

For this, I have a table of about 30 different job titles:

```
01 CEO
02 CFO
03 Key Account Manager
...
29 Window Cleaner
30 Dishwasher
```

I'm trying to find a way to generate one of these titles from a few different variables like name, age, education history, work history and so on. I wan't it to be somewhat random but still consistent so that the same variables always result in the same title.

I also wan't the different variables to have ***some*** impact on the result. Lower numbers are "better" jobs and higher numbers are "worse" jobs, but it doesn't have to be very accurate, just not completely random.

So take these two people as an example.

```
Name: Joe Smith
Number of previous employers: 10
Number of years education: 8
Age: 56

Name: Samantha Smith
Number of previous employers: 1
Number of years education: 0
Age: 19
```

Now the reason I wan't the name in there is to have a bit of randomness, so that two co-workers of the same age with the same background doesn't get exactly the same title. So I was thinking of using the number of letters in the name to mix it up a bit.

Now I can generate consistent numbers in an infinite number of ways, like `the number of letters in the name * age * years of education *  number of employers`. This would come out as 35 840 for Joe Smith and 247 for Samantha Smith. But I wan't it to be a number between 1-30 where Samantha is closer to 25-30 and Joe is closer to 1-5.

Maybe this is more of a math problem than a programming problem, but I have seen a lot of "What's your pirate name?" and similar apps out there and I can't figure out how they work. "What's your pirate name?" might be a bad example, since it's probably completely random and I wan't my variables to matter some, but the idea is the same.

**What I have tried**

I tried adding weights to variable groups so I would get an easier number to use in my calculations.

```
Age
01-20 5
20-30 4
30-40 3
40-50 2
...

Years of education
00-01 0
01-02 1
02-03 2
04-05 3
...
```

Add them together and play around with those numbers, but there was a lot of problems like everyone ending up in pretty much the same mid-range (no one got to be CEO or dishwasher, everyone was somewhere in the middle), not to mention how messy the code was.

Is there a good way to accomplish what I want to do without having to build a massive math engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int numberOfTitles = 30;

var semiRandomID    = person.Name.GetHashCode() 
                    ^ person.NumberOfPreviousEmployers.GetHashCode() 
                    ^ person.NumberOfYearsEducation.GetHashCode()
                    ^ person.Age.GetHashCode();

var semiRandomTitle = Math.Abs(semiRandomID) % numberOfTitles;

// adjust semiRandomTitle as you see fit
semiRandomTitle += ((person.Age / 10) - 2);
semiRandomTitle += (person.NumberOfYearsEducation / 2);
```

The `semiRandomID` is a number that is generated from unique hashes of each component. The numbers are unique so that you will always generate the same number for "Joe" for example, but they don't mean anything. It's just a number. So we take all those unique numbers and generate one job title out of the 30 available. Every person has the same chance to get each job title (probably some math freak will proof that there's egde cases to the contrary, but for all practical, non-cryptographic means, it's sufficient).

Now each person has one job title assigned that looks random. However, as it's math and not randomness, they will get the same every time.

Now lets assume Joe got Taxi-Driver, the number 20. However, he has 10 years of formal education, so you decide you want to have that aspect have some weight. You could just add the years onto the job title number, but that would make anyone with 30 years of college parties CEO, so you decide (arbitrarily) that each year of education counts for half a job title. You add (NumberOfYearsEducation / 2) to the job title.

Lets assume Jane got CIO, the number 5. However, she  is only 22 years old, a little young to be that high on the list. Again, you could just add the years onto the job title number, but that would make anyone with 30 years of age a CEO, so you decide (arbitrarily) that each year counts as 1/10 of a job title. In addition, you think that being very young should instead subtract from the job title. All years below the first 20 should indeed be a negative weight. So the formula would be ((Age / 10) - 2). One point for each 10 years of age, with the first 2 counting as negative.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you explain in short what is going on here? `semiRandomID` always seems to come out negative, but that could be solved with `Math.Abs(semiRandomID)` I suppose. Where do I add ((age / 10) - 2)?

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I needed! Any idea why the numbers came out negative? Doesn't really matter, but just curious.

Comment: Well, they are just calculated numbers and a negative number is valid as long as it's unique in one direction (i.e. "Joe" always giving the same number). I used `Math.Abs` in the edit.